# Is there any ritual or ceremony for House-Warming?

Tags: rituals

I'm thinking house-warming for our new house so Is there any ritual or ceremony for house-warming in Buddhism and how do they perform? In which sutta it is discoursed?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, we invite Sangha for a meal.
After the meal, they chant some blessings.
In Sri Lanka, we have overnight Pirith chanting in the new house.

Comment: Can you explain more? I've to request a monk for house-warming but I want to know rituals and source.

Comment: It depends on the monk. There is no Sutta to support this. In Sri Lanka, it is just the culture. You get some idea from the following YouTube video.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8POyDHfKzU

Comment: Yes, I also got about Sri Lanka regarding house-warming as you said. Even it is cultural thing to perform I'd want it here in India and may wherever we live. So I've to ask monk in first place. Thanks a lot.